# Is there any difference between these two capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, noise, emc, emi-filtering

I have these capacitors and want to use them for the Y-caps of a CM-EMI filter.

I know the first one is undoubtedly suitable for my application as all information such as Y and X safety classes are printed on it, but I'm not sure about the second one. Is this the same type of capacitor as the first one? Can I use it as Y-cap in the EMI filter? Are ceramic capacitors and lenit capacitors the same?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't do it.   Without the safety lab certifications (i.e logos on the device), you're in a legally indefensible position should somebody get hurt.

Comment: "back in the day", they used to use standard Electrolytic capacitors to tie a live line to ground.   Meaning you were one failed piece of wax paper away from an electrically live chassis.  They are called a "death cap" for a reason (you can google that phrase and find out all about it....   The capacitors, not the mushroom  LOL)    i.e. https://robrobinette.com/Death_Cap_and_Ground_Switch.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

hm, safety critical application, but component of unknown origin with uncertain characteristics: Just don't.

There's no good reason to use an unknown component in a place where failure can lead to electrocution or fire.

Comment: If you've really gone to the effort and cost of implementing class X or class Y design, you'd make very sure you'd print it on the case. You might also get fraudsters adding it to unsuitable caps. But if it's not printed on it in any way assume not. Class X and Class Y generally requires a different design, not only a certification process, so they're not going to be "accidentally" suitable either.